# Show this inequality for a normally distributed random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be normally distributed with mean $\mu=0$ and variance $\sigma^2>0$.
I want to show that given  any real number $a \geq 0$ we have $\mathbb{P}(\mid X \mid \leq a) \leq \frac{a}{\sigma}$
How can I show this inequality in a simple way? I tried doing it just by computing it with the probability density function, but then you get an annoying calculation with the error function. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac 1  {\sqrt {2 \pi} \sigma} \int_{-a}^{a} e^{-x^{2}/2\sigma^{2}} dx \leq \frac1  {\sqrt 2 \pi \sigma } \int_{-a}^{a}  dx <\frac a {\sigma}$ since $\sqrt {\frac2  {\pi}} <1$.